# How Jhipster uses JDL-studio to add relationships in the "Authority" entity

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

I am now developing an organization, but when I use JDL-studio to add a many-to-many relationship to the authority, I can not find the authority entity. But can find this User entity class. please help me, thank you!
I'm using jhipstter 4.6.1 now.

run yo jhipster:import-jdl /Users/uqing/Downloads/jhipster-jde.jh
The following error occurred：

In the relationship between Role and Authority, Authority is not declared.',

message: 'In the relationship between Role and Authority, Authority is not declared.',

[this is jdl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN4g2.jpg)

Comment: `Authority` is not a normal JHipster entity, you can't generate it nor modify it using the generator, it's the same restrictions as for `User` which are documented here: https://jhipster.github.io/managing-relationships/

Comment: I must admit that I'm not sure special handling that exists in generator for User has also been implemented for Authority. Anyway, for further help you should edit your question and paste your JDL.

Comment: User is not a normal entity, but it can be identified. Is it only Authority that is not recognized?Or is it the wrong name？

Comment: Error message might be misleading, Authority is the right name. To verify it, just create a many-to-many relationship to the Authority entity, but the other entity Organization) must be the owner of the relationship

Comment: I am going to check how jdl-studio works in depth. However looking at the image you shared.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN4g2.jpg


Is there a typo on line 33.

`Role{authority} to Authority{Role}`

instead of 

`Role{authority} to Authority{role}`

Answer (score 0):

As `Authority` is just a table containing one column of string type, the link can be done with a simple string column. For example

```
entity MyEntity {
  authority String required
  value String
}
```

In the database, you'll have something like this:

```
Authority | Value
--------------------
ROLE_A    | Value 1
ROLE_B    | Value 2
```